# Create clones of root model observable array within objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a clone of an self.tags observable array within each line object I create, where self.field_name reflects the value but self.field_value is an independant value for each Line object. I'm getting a bit mixed up how to do this, do I need a manual subscription to only update one of the values?

```
function TechnicalViewModel(){

    var root = this;

    function Tag(data){
        var self = this;
        self.field_name = ko.observable(data.field_name)
        self.field_value = ko.observable(data.field_value)
    }


    root.tags = ko.observableArray([
    { 
        new Tag(field_name : 'tag_name_1', field_value : '',
        new Tag(field_name : 'tag_name_2', field_value : '',
        new Tag(field_name : 'tag_name_3', field_value : ''
    }])


    function Line(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.tags = root.tags;
    }

    root.lines = ko.observableArray([]))

}
```

Comment: Do you need to deep clone the tag names? You can `.slice` but it depends on that really.

Comment: Yeah I think so, I'm trying to use the root.tags as the foundation for each self.tags, but with independent field_values

Answer (score 0):

Ko mapping pluggin can be used for cloning.

```
 //Use this function as constructor function
 function Tag(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.field_name = data.field_name;
    self.field_value = data.field_value;
 }

 function Line(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.tags = ko.mapping.fromJS(root.tags); //mapping pluggin will make a copy of tags
    self.remove = function (data) {
        self.tags.remove(data);
    }
    self.add = function () {
        self.tags.push(new Tag({
            field_name: 'new tag_name',
            field_value: ''
        }));
    }
 }
```

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/bE847/5/)

Comment: Looks like its very close to what I'm after! All I need to do know now is how to reflect changes in the root.tags observable within the objects, so if I add/remove a Tag object dynamically, the Line objects are updated.

Comment: You can add add/remove methods in Line function. see the updated solution.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained clearly, its very close to what I was after, but its the root.tags array I'd like to add/remove tags from,a and have the updates to the field_names populate through the Line objects.

Comment: I'm thinking the solution lies somewghere in the custom mapping options e.g

`var mapping = {
     'observe': ["field_name"]
}

self.tags = ko.mapping.fromJS(root.tags, mapping);`

Comment: you want to update and remove the tag value individually right? have you seen updated fiddle?

Comment: Yeah it's on the right path, I was trying to add/remove to root.lines and have the Tag objects repopulate in the Line objects. Kind of

http://jsfiddle.net/GXd7P/8/

Comment: Would re-mapping the objects on add/remove work, re-writing the field_value values where it isn't empty?

Comment: I saw your fiddle but i think you can not have add/remove directly attached to root it should be associated with Line. http://jsfiddle.net/GXd7P/11/